# The OP consistently edits the question resolving the issue, thus invalidating all the answers and the question itself

Tags: discussion, rollback-wars

For this question [How to allocate 3D array in CPP using template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154474/how-to-allocate-3d-array-in-cpp-using-template) the answer is to change
`T*** Alloc(int w, int h, int d)` to
`T*** Alloc3D::Alloc(int w, int h, int d)`

The user edited the question reflecting this change, thus invalidating all answers and the question itself. The community reverted this change and the OP changed it back multiple times.

Should the question be flagged? Can a question be locked from editing by it’s owner? Is there any action that should take place, or just leave it as it is?

Comment: Am I missing something? The OP added `Alloc3D::`, you removed it (rolled back the post), then there was just *one* more edit by the OP *soon after your rollback* that added `Alloc3D::` back and also changed some more things. I suspect the OP was in the process of adding more things when you rolled back the post.

Comment: @AndriyM I am sorry, didn’t think that the user was already editing the question when I rolled back. Didn’t look at time stamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rollback war (repeated rollbacks by the same user) raises an automatic flag; a moderator will come looking soon enough and lock the post if this continues.

In this specific case, there has only been one roll-back, so if the OP continues to edit the correction back in, feel free to flag the post for moderator attention manually; use the 'other' option and explain what is happening.

In the meantime, leave a comment educating the user; explain that questions are there for future visitors too and that by editing the question they made the question and answers useless for those visitors.

Comment: It could very well be inadvertent on the OP's side. They could just be making another edit when @bolov rolled back their post.

Comment: @AndriyM: perhaps; it *could* indeed be a simple edit conflict.