# Is the original poster of an answer allowed to destructively edit his own content?

Tags: discussion, edits, licensing

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29198809/revisions

In this case, the OP wrote a well-received post and then just "destroyed" his post by editing it.

Is he allowed to do so, because it is his own content?
Or could he be forced to at least not change his post from on-topic to off-topic?

Comment: It's generally considered destructive behaviour and should be rolled back. As for content - it's not his content as soon as he posts it.

Comment: [Bad things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288229/1070452) can happen to those who do that

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288524/560648

Comment: @J.Steen It's still the author's, even if the author no longer has full control of how it gets used, and I don't see how you could make any even remotely legitimate claim otherwise. What you say would mean that once you post something to SO, you lose the right to use it yourself as you see fit, that you yourself are *also* bound by the CC license. That's nonsense.

Comment: @hvd Semantics - even if that's hideously important in legal matters. What I meant was it's no longer his to control and decide over. It's indeed under CC license. Yes, it's his content. Bad choice of words on my part.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is he allowed to do so, because it is his own content?

No. Everyone agrees to the CC:Wiki license that when they post content. It licenses contributions to the community and that license can't be revoked.

The user does have the option of requesting their name be removed from the post through [disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts).

> To request disassociation, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page. In the form, say you want to disassociate a post and include the URL.

---

#### What can you do?

If you see this type of behavior, you can roll back the post to a previous version. If the original author continues to destroy the content it is advised that you avoid a [rollback war](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267883/189134). An automatic flag will be raised after multiple rollbacks by the same user. You are, however, able to raise a moderator flag (using the `Other` option and explaining what is happening) before going through multiple rollbacks.